# How to copy files from JARs to WAR in Gradle?

Tags: jar, resources, copy, gradle, war

I need to copy specific files that are in JARs into specific directory in WAR, using Gradle.
My code:

```
war.doFirst {
    for(file in classpath) {
        FileTree tree = zipTree(file)
        FileTree treeResources = tree.matching { include "META-INF/resources/*" }

        String folderName = 'destinationFolder'
        {
            treeResources.each { 
                File resources -> copy {
                    from resources
                    String dest = war.destinationDir.name + "/" + war.archiveName + "/" + folderName
                    into dest
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Problem: the "dest" value is incorrect, instead of being in the created WAR file, it is something like "libs/mywar-1.0.war/destinationFolder".

Answer (score 1):

You'll want something like:

```
war {
    into("destinationFolder") {
        from { classpath.collect { zipTree(it) } }
        include "META-INF/resources/**"
    }
}
```

Comment: It works, except: include "META-INF/resources/**" includes META-INF/resources folder, but I need files and folders inside of resources, without the resources folder.